# Manga/webcomic about two grandpas using VR to meet as anime girls and then falling in love

Tags: story-identification, manga, virtual-worlds

Both grandpas have cute anime girl models, one with more normal eyes and the other with droopy eyes, which matches him IRL. They go on adventures in the VR world and fall in love and get married in VR. There is a scene where they go on a train into nothingness but I'm not sure if that was a VR thing or a dream. Also we find out droopy eyed grandpa has a heart disease and may soon stop playing as he is going in for surgery. The other one eventually goes to find him in real life, and he's still alive. Also there's some funny stuff as the grandpa's grandson observes tbe romance

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When and where did you read this?

Comment: How futuristic is the VR?

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is ***[An Older Guy's VR First Love](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/giwkx4w/vr-ojisan-no-hatsukoi)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Naoki is an older guy, 40 years old to be exact. He lives a mundane single life in the real world but enjoys venturing into the VR world as a female avatar. One day in the VR world, he meets a young happy-go-lucky girl named Honami, whom he slowly becomes attracted to... But who is the real Honami and what will become of their relationship?

Naoki is a middle-aged virgin who uses VR to escape his lonely life in the real world. His VR avatar is a school girl and he meets and falls in love with Honami, another female avatar.

In one scene, they board a train to the edge of the world together, and Honami says she might not be able to come to the VR world anymore, as she's sick in the real world and is due to undergo surgery. Shortly after that, they accidentally meet in the real world, and it turns out that Honami is a grandfather.

Honami's grandson, Aoi, is initally weirded out when he sees Naoki in Honami's real world apartment and discovers that they're lovers in the VR world, but ultimately accepts their relationship, and even hangs out with them in the VR world using his own avatar.

Naoki subsequently proposes to Honami in the VR world and their avatars get married.

[image]

[image]

Comment: 40 is old? I guess I'm past my warranty...

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - It's a matter of perspective. Japanese culture is notoriously obsessed with youth, and most anime/manga protagonists are under 20. So, by those standards, a 40-year-old protagonist is relatively old.